# Running a Flask application in PyCharm IDE

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

Hello stackoverflow community!

I have a question and I couldn't find any answers..

So I have a virtual Debain 20.04 Server and I'm accessing it using PuTTY to host my flask application (with uWSGI and nginx).
But it feels so confusing without an IDE.

**So my question is: Are there any ways to run a Flask application using uWSGI and nginx in an IDE like Pycharm or vscode?**

Deploy a flask application on Debain with uWSGI and nginx: https://www.vultr.com/docs/deploy-a-flask-website-on-nginx-with-uwsgi/

Answer (score 0):

> So my question is: Are there any ways to run a Flask application using uWSGI and nginx in an IDE like Pycharm or vscode?

You can run Flask application using multiple web servers, you do not need to use Nginx or uWSGI.

For a local development, it is recommend you run your application using [a mini web server like Waitress](https://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/waitress/en/latest/) that makes it is easy to run any WSGI protocol based application locally (no servers needed).

You are still likely to learn some terminal. Though in theory all actions can be done through an IDE, most of the tutorials assume that you need to know UNIX command line basics, because you are going to need to know those any case to be a productive as a Python developer. Figuring how to do it through an IDE will probably take more time than learning to use Pycharm's integrated terminal for the development.

Here is an example how I am working with a locally running Waitress server (w/code hot reload) when working in PyCharm IDE:

[image]